# Unable to access old account (can it be merged)

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid

I had no idea I had the following old zombie account on SO until a friend asked if it was me and no idea what email address it was created with. Any idea how I would merge it into my current account (the one this is posted under). I'm wondering whether maybe it was created using @googlemail.com and when this changed to @gmail.com my account spit?  Regardless - I can't seem to get into it.

If there was a way I could log in using just the userId 82882 I could probably remember the password (assuming it's not solely accessible via an OpenID account I'm no longer aware of)

https://stackoverflow.com/users/82882/owen-thomson

Comment: Not quite.  I don't know the email address of the account used to create it so I can't log in and I don't have access to the account so I can't merge it myself.

Comment: them email the team via the contact us link in the footer. These types of issues cannot be addressed on Meta.