# Merge old Stack Overflow account with new one

Tags: support, user-accounts, email, merge-accounts

I made this account a couple of years ago, however this email address is no longer in use (it exists, but I can't access it).

Is it possible to merge this Stack Overflow account with my new one?

P.S. The only way I can use to log in to this account (and prove it's mine) is because I'm automatically logged in in the app.

Update: I do not know the password to this account.

Comment: You still know the passwords to both accounts, right? In that case, whether the e-mail address is active would be irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, but to use that feature you need to prove ownership in both accounts. Apart from being logged in on this account I can't prove it as I can't access the according email address.

Comment: No, I do not know the password of this account...

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237362/unable-to-access-old-account-can-it-be-merged. Contact SE directly

Comment: Thanks, how do I contact them from within the app? I don't see this possibility.

Comment: @AmpiSevere Well click contact at the bottom of a website page?

Comment: I couldn't find the contact link in the app so I used my other account to contact them via the web page. Sadly the merging doesn't work if you cannot access both emails, so I'll contact them again differently. Thanks for the help!